# invalid syntax in CUDA kernel on google colab

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, google-colaboratory

I tried running the following code using Google Colab.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
__global__ void add(int *a , int *b, int *c) {
*c = *a + *b;
}
int main() {
int d = 9;
int *a, *b, *c;

cudaMalloc((void **)&a, sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void **)&b, sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void **)&c, sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpy(a, &d, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(b, &d, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
add<<<1,1>>>();
//cudaMemcpy(e, c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(&d,c sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf("Answer : %d", d);

return 0;
}
```

I, however, got this error :

```
File "<ipython-input-4-91a227fc2a65>", line 4
    __global__ void add() {
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The kernel looks correct to me.. Please suggest on what the error might have been.

Comment: You cannot directly run that CUDA code in Python as you are trying to

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of I can see straight off the bat.

You are not calling your CUDA kernel with any arguments (add your device pointers there).

Another thing is that you are missing a comma between c and sizeof(int) in your `cudaMemcpy` from the device to the host.

Finally, I was able to follow the steps I found on [this](https://medium.com/@iphoenix179/running-cuda-c-c-in-jupyter-or-how-to-run-nvcc-in-google-colab-663d33f53772) and run your code (after fixing the above errors of course). To answer the original question, the python interpreter doesn't know what void means, so you have to inform it that this is not normal python code.

Here is my output ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO0Qk.jpg))

Comment: This worked. I had also forgotten to add %%cu to the cell.